# Add quotes to first line of CSV

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I wish to modify the first row of a CSV (comma-separated file) which contains headings by adding quotes. It's a very large file, I was trying to use AWK for this problem.

Before:

```
id,var1,var2
1,0.11,0.44
2,0.22,0.55
3,0.33,0.66
```

After:

```
"id","var1","var2"
1,0.11,0.44
2,0.22,0.55
3,0.33,0.66
```

Something like this, which adds quotes for all columns, but for all rows:

```
awk -F"," -v quote="'" -v OFS="','" '$1=$1 {print quote $0 quote}' input.csv > output.csv
```

I just want quotes around the first line. I was trying to use NR, but couldn't get the syntax correct to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = "\047" $i "\047"} 1' file
'id','var1','var2'
1,0.11,0.44
2,0.22,0.55
3,0.33,0.66
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted double quotes in headers then use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = "\042" $i "\042"} 1' file
"id","var1","var2"
1,0.11,0.44
2,0.22,0.55
3,0.33,0.66
```

Comment: Don't use `\x27`, use `\047` instead. Did the question change? It's asking for double quotes but the answers are adding single quotes.

Comment: Actually OP was using `-v quote="'"` in the code shown. Changed to `\047`, thanks.

Comment: Yeah but if his code did what he wanted he wouldn't be asking the question :-). His desired output shows double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to GNU sed:

```
sed '1s/\b\w*\b/"&"/g' file
```

Output:

```
"id" "var1" "var2"
1 0.11 0.44
2 0.22 0.55
3 0.33 0.66
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{gsub(/,/,"\",\""); $0="\""$0"\""} 1' file
"id","var1","var2"
1,0.11,0.44
2,0.22,0.55
3,0.33,0.66
```